# Simple HTML DOM Parser - Get Path

Tags: php, dom

I'm slowly trying to use [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to extract some html from a page and insert the html code into the current page. (I'm a PHP newbie)

In the example, a person would enter page name only like c.html.  I need the php to look in the current page's: div navbar a href that ends w/ $pg, when it finds that need to get the full href so I have the path, so it can be used to go to that page and pull some specified div.

I have this so far, but the path is not echoing out:

```
<?php
include_once '%resource(simple_html_dom.php)%';
$pg = 'c.html';
echo 'Page: ' . $pg . '<br />';  // Works
$html = file_get_html();  // needs to look in current pg
foreach($html->find('#navbar a[href$=$pg]') as $path) // Doesn't work
  echo 'Path: ' . $path;
$html = file_get_html($path);
foreach($html->find('#testdiv2') as $ret)
  echo $ret;
?>
```

Thanks for the help.

Updated code:

```
<?php
include_once 'path/to/resource/simple_html_dom.php';
$pg = 'c.html';
echo 'Page: ' . $pg . '<br />';
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT)
foreach($html->find(sprintf('#navbar a[href=%s]',$pg)) as $path)
  echo 'Path: ' . $path;
$html = file_get_html($path);
foreach($html->find('#testdiv2') as $ret)
  echo $ret;
?>
```

- The include once line was a special plugin format - I changed it to show an example path to the file - which should be readable by php, right?
- In defining the function file_get_html (remember I'm using Simple HTML DOM Parser): How do I define $url for the current page? (I need this to be automatically defined)
  Does the %s mean 'ends with'? (I didn't see that in the docs I looked at)
- Do I need to call the function in the 1st foreach or assign $html to the function? (Does it need brackets or an ending ; ?)
- For 2nd foreach, if $html is redefined, then it will run ok?

Could you explain these to me @Baba, as this is all new to me :)

Comment: Can someone please help me with these questions & get the script running - thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following is not not a valid way to include a file

```
include_once '%resource(simple_html_dom.php)%';
```

It should be something like

```
include_once __DIR__.'/simple_html_dom.php';
```

`file_get_html` expect at least one parameter which is `$url`

```
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT)
```

I also want to believe your find should look somthing like this

```
foreach($html->find(sprintf('#navbar a[href=%s]',$pg)) as $path)
```